# Display value in input field doesn't work with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to display a value in an input field with vanilla Javascript, but weirdly, it didn't work until I used JQuery

Example with vanilla JS

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
document.getElementsByName("plan_date").value = today;
```

```html
<input name="plan_date" type="text">
```

And here same example with JQuery

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
$('input[name=plan_date]').val(today);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="plan_date" type="text">
```

Can someone explain to me what am I getting wrong?

Comment: document.getElementsByName is plural. You need to add [0] or use `document.querySelector('input[name=plan_date]').value=today;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost Done .You missing to mention `[0]`.because the `name` attribute is multiple selector of the element.so you could mention as 0.Then only its target the first element

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
document.getElementsByName("plan_date")[0].value = today;
```

```html
<input name="plan_date" type="text">
```

Comment: You have enough rep to vote to close as typo. It is not only a typo-type question, it is a huge duplicate

Answer (score 1):

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
document.getElementsByName("plan_date")[0].value = today;
```

```html
<input name="plan_date" type="text">
```

`document.getElementsByName` returns an array of element with same name, so access like this `document.getElementsByName("plan_date")[0].value = today;`

Answer (score 0):

**getElementsByName("plan_date")** returns an array

try with

```
document.getElementsByName("plan_date")[0].value = today;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `getElementsByName` returns an array. So you could use `document.getElementsByName("plan_date")[0].value = today;` or add an id to the element like so:

```
document.getElementById("element_id").value = today
```